# Best practice height/character count for text in tategaki format

Tags: typesetting

On a web page, what is the maximum good practice height (in pixels) for text written in tategaki format?

A height of about 500px looks good to me, which is about 40 characters.

Are there heights either are too long, or too short, which make reading uncomfortable/difficult?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure this question is best suited for this site: there is also GraphicDesign.SE, which might be the natural alternative. (To be honest, I'm a bit puzzled as to why you ask for measurements in pixels, but anyway.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think 40 characters per line is a good upper limit. This is how novels are typically typeset on paper. See this [image search results for 小説 + 組版](https://search.yahoo.co.jp/image/search?p=%E5%B0%8F%E8%AA%AC%20%E7%B5%84%E7%89%88&aq=-1&oq=&ei=UTF-8). Lines longer than this start to be unfamiliar and difficult to read. If you care for smartphone screens, 30 characters per line should be safer.